# Customized parameter logging when using aspect oriented programing

Tags: aop, aspectj, unity-interception

All the examples I've seen that use aspect oriented programming for logging either log just class, method name and duration, and if they log parameters and return values they simply use ToString(). I need to have more control over what is logged. For example I want to skip passwords, or in some cases log all properties of an object but in other cases just the id property. 
Any suggestions? I looked at AspectJ in Java and Unity interception in C# and could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try introducing parameter annotations to augment your parameters with some attributes. One of those attributes could signal to skip logging the parameter, another one could be used to specify a converter class for the string representation.

With the following annotations:

```java
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Log {
}


@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface SkipLogging {
}

@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface ToStringWith {
    Class<? extends Function<?, String>> value();
}
```

the aspect could look like this:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public aspect LoggingAspect {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

    pointcut loggableMethod(): execution(@Log * *..*.*(..));

    before(): loggableMethod() {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) thisJoinPoint.getSignature();
        Parameter[] parameters = signature.getMethod()
            .getParameters();
        String message = IntStream.range(0, parameters.length)
            .filter(i -> this.isLoggable(parameters[i]))
            .<String>mapToObj(i -> toString(parameters[i], thisJoinPoint.getArgs()[i]))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", 
                    "method execution " + signature.getName() + "(", ")"));
        Logger methodLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(
                thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getDeclaringType());
        methodLogger.debug(message);
    }

    private boolean isLoggable(Parameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getAnnotation(SkipLogging.class) == null;
    }

    private String toString(Parameter parameter, Object value) {
        ToStringWith toStringWith = parameter.getAnnotation(ToStringWith.class);
        if (toStringWith != null) {
            Class<? extends Function<?, String>> converterClass = 
                    toStringWith.value();
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Function<Object, String> converter = (Function<Object, String>) 
                    converterClass.newInstance();
                String str = converter.apply(value);
                return String.format("%s='%s'", parameter.getName(), str);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Couldn't instantiate toString converter for logging " 
                        + converterClass.getName(), e);
                return String.format("%s=<error converting to string>", 
                        parameter.getName());
            }
        } else {
            return String.format("%s='%s'", parameter.getName(), String.valueOf(value));
        }
    }

}
```

Test code:

```java
public static class SomethingToStringConverter implements Function<Something, String> {

    @Override
    public String apply(Something something) {
        return "Something nice";
    }

}

@Log
public void test(
        @ToStringWith(SomethingToStringConverter.class) Something something,
        String string, 
        @SkipLogging Class<?> cls, 
        Object object) {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
// execution of this method should log the following message:
// method execution test(something='Something nice', string='some string', object='null')
    test(new Something(), "some string", Object.class, null);
}
```

I used Java 8 Streams API in my answer for it's compactness, you could convert the code to normal Java code if you don't use Java 8 features or need better efficiency. It's just to give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Is this they way interception based logging is usually used? The method declaration looks a bit cluttered with all the annotations, and the ToStringConverter isn't type safe. How is this code maintained, when some aspects will only fail in runtime?

Comment: This code I've posted is only scratching the surface of what you could do in terms of logging. If you feel the method signatures involving logged methods are too verbose you could introduce meaningful defaults based on types, where you declare the logging behavior on the class itself, so you can skip the explicit `@ToStringWith` or `@SkipLogging` annotations from the method declarations. This is more like an example of how you could do this kind of tracing/logging with AspectJ.

Comment: What about the type safety? The ToStringConverter has to cast from an object. Is there no type safe solution?

Comment: You're right in the sense that it's kinda awkward to have your converter class do an explicit class, and I've probably chosen the wrong place for the explicit cast (that is, in the converter class itself). But the thing is, we can't do without an explicit cast, either in the converter class, or the aspect itself, where we create an instance of the converter. That's because there's no way to tie an annotation value's (`@ToStringWith.value()`) generic type signature to the parameter type to which the annotation is applied. But you are right, that it's probably better to do the cast in the aspect

Comment: The main thing that is still bothering me with this approach is that we lose compile time safety. If I change the type of the parameter, I don't think the compiler will warn.